# Rotation is very odd - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: animation

A newbie to Blender here. I have a scene with some objects. One is a crescent that I created by adding a cylinder, rotating it on it's Y axis by 90 degrees and scaling it on the X axis and finally boolean slicing it in half to create the shape I want.

If I say R X to rotate it on the X axis, I am able to do that and it rotates to the position that I want (90 degrees). However, I notice that the rotation value for X in the menu on the right has changed to 90 as expected. But, the Y has changed from 90 to minus 90 and the Z has changed from 0 to 90.

Normally I might not really care about this but I am attempting to keyframe this animation and unlike when I perform the rotation using R X, the animation rotates on all 3 axises. The animation is supposed to be a spinning half disk but the animation creates something that rotates on all 3 axises.

What am I doing wrong here?

2 screenshots are attached. One before I do the rotation with x at 0, y at 90 and z at zero and then the results after I do the rotation. Any help greatly appreciated :)

Before:

[image: Text]

And After:

[image: Text]

Comment: your image links are broken, kindly remove or update with another image

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong.  This is just the way that Euler angles work.

There are two main issues with Euler angles: gimbal lock (or as I prefer, wonky Euler interpolation, because I think people misunderstand gimbal lock all the time because of how it's named), and aliasing.

Wonky Euler interpolation means that Euler angles do not interpolate their rotation along the shortest path.  My favorite metaphor for this involves airplanes.  Imagine you are in Reykjavic, Iceland and you want to fly to Anchorage, USA.  What path do you take?  If you take the shortest path, you will fly north, and fly very close to the North Pole.  But if, instead, you look on a latitude-longitude map of the Earth and just plot a straight line on that map, you will fly west over Canada.  Your flight path will be a straight line on your (distorted) 2D map, but once laid over the spherical globe, it will no longer be a straight line and will instead have torque.  Plotting a straight line on the 2D map like that is how Euler angles interpolate.  Your flight is the rotation, around the center of the Earth, described by interpolating from one Euler angle to another.

The difference between the path given by Euler interpolation and by shortest-distance interpolation (which would be quaternion interpolation) is big in some cases, small in others-- just like the Euler/quaternion difference flying between Anchorage and Reykjavic is bigger than the difference when flying between Bogota and Singapore.  By starting your Y rotation at 90 degrees, when you are evaluating an XYZ Euler angle, you're guaranteeing a large difference-- you're starting near the north pole.

"Aliasing" means that there are multiple values of one measure that correspond to a single value of something else.  Here, we're talking about multiple Euler angles corresponding to single orientations: the Euler angles have *aliases*, other values that give the exact same result.  The easiest example to imagine in your head is rotate 180 degrees in X, then 180 degrees in Y, then no rotation in Z; think about how this is the exact same rotation as rotating 0 degrees in X and Y and then 180 degrees in Z.  Those two Euler triplets correspond to the exact same 3D orientation.  This is far from the only orientation that gets aliased; there are actually twice as many Euler angle triplets in the -180, 180 range as there are orientations.  But Blender needs a single set of Euler values to interpolate between.  It chooses the angles it provides, for a particular transformation, based on its best guess of how things should interpolate, but it's just dumb software, and it can't always choose right.  The Euler angles we see are not always the Euler angles we expect, because there are multiple sets of Eulers that correspond to the actual orientation.

Usually, when we need only limited amounts of rotation (plus or minus 360 degrees), and it's all going to be in a single axis, and, in Blender, we don't mind that the interpolation will never be linear, the easiest thing to do here is to change the rotation mode to quaternion, in properties/object data/transform/rotation mode.  Once we do that, our interpolation will be along the shortest path.  However, that also means that our rotation transform numbers won't necessarily make a lot of sense to us.  (Quaternions, as implemented by Blender, are not aliased, but in most other applications they are; but because we're probably not concerned about the actual numbers, we probably don't care about quaternion aliasing.  We just want to make sure that we stay on this or that side of 0 for our W component if we don't want to do extra rotations.)

In other situations, there can be reasons that we want Euler angles.  In that case, we're best off if we never deviate far from n, 0, 0 rotation.  The first angle is basically free, as its independent of the other angles, but the other angles are dependent.  How can we assure that we don't deviate far from that rotation?  One way is to apply rotation when we have the object close to the middle of its reasonable rotations.  Another important technique is to choose an Euler order (again, in properties/object data/transform/rotation mode) such that the main axis in which we want to rotate the object is the first axis of our Euler order.

Finally, when we don't like the angles that Blender has given us for a particular orientation, we can always edit them.  We can enter numbers manually in the rotation fields and then keyframe rotation.  Or, we can edit keyframe values in a graph editor viewport.  The numbers Blender hands us are not immutable, God-given facts; they're just numbers, and we're always free to tell Blender to shove it with its best guesses.

Comment: Sadly, just changing the numbers does not produce the lateral rotation that I am looking for for this disk object.  I exported it to an FBX and imported that into Fusion and I was able to rotate it there just fine but selecting every other type of coordinate system in Blender does not give me the results I need sadly.